# sys_ui_policy vs catalog_ui_policy in servicenow

Tags: servicenow

If I create `sys_ui_policy` will that also apply to catalog items or do I explicitly need to create the same `catalog_ui_policy`?

In terms of building the UI policy both are some just addition filed on `catalog_ui_policy` -> `Catalog item | cat_item`

**Catalog UI Policy:**
[image]

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**UI Policy:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sys_ui_policies would also apply to the catalog items.
But you could not use the variables as conditions. So, if you're in the catalog, I would definitely use catalog ui policies.